# Updated from Javax to Jakarta affecting Hibernate Sequence

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jakarta-migration

Recently we have upgraded the springboot app to version 3.0 where the `Javax` has been relocated to `Jakarta`.

Whenever a new object is created in DB it is lesser than the actual `hibernate_sequence`value provided in the DB.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Could you share some code sample ?

Comment: you mean the pom file?

Comment: Yes and the declaration of the `hibernate_sequence` :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes but Im unable to add the code so I need to create a new issue?